# Capybara testing with javascript

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I am fairly new to rails and I need to test code that has javascript associated to it. After some research I found out that it isn't that difficult.

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara

So now I add ":js => true" to my examples in my specs and all is well. To get this working you have to update your spec_helper file to not run your tests as transactional and add in the database_cleaner gem to clear the data each time a test is run.

I get that it is great to now be able to test your code that has javascript in it, but surely it is quite annoying to have your database cleared every time? Since I am fairly new I still use the front end to make decisions. It is very difficult to do pure TDD when I am not 100% of syntax and to implement things in rails. Every time I want to see what things look like through the front end I need to recreate all the data manually. I could probably write a script to insert default data, this seems like writing more code because of my tests (which might be what I should do ... I am not sure).

Is there another way to run my tests with javascript so that my tests are transactional still?  I am running my testing environment with guard so every time I save a spec file my database gets cleared (users and all)!

Is there perhaps a way to run guard for only the test environment and preserve my development data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, my database.yml was incorrect. My testing environment was pointing to the same as my development so the data was cleared every time.

Works perfectly now.